# PHP - Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is my script for the getting comments and replies. It's not nested since I dont care about it and I just want to be able to display the comments in a similar manner to youtubes.

```
    <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'DBConfig.php';

// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser2,$HostPass2,$DatabaseName2);

 // Creating SQL query
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.id = 22 ";

$queryReplies = $con -> prepare('SELECT * FROM replies WHERE replies.id = ? ');


if ($con->connect_error) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
}
else {
    if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        if( $result->num_rows > 0) {

        $post_arr = array();

         while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) // First loop for comment
         {
           $commentID = $row['uniqueID'];
           extract($row);

           $post_item = array(
               'uniqueID' => $uniqueID,
            'comment' => $comment,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'user' => $user
        );

        $queryReplies->bind_param("s",$commentID);
        $resultReplies = $con->$queryReplies->execute();

           while($rowReplies = $resultReplies->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) // Second loop for replies to comment
           {
                extract($rowReplies);

                $reply_array = array(
                    'comment' => $comment,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'user' => $user
                );
                array_push($post_item,$reply_array);

           }

           array_push($post_arr,$post_item);

         }
         echo json_encode($post_arr);

        }
    }
}

 mysqli_close($con);

 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

So basically, I want it to return chunks. I have a comment and replies table in my DB.

It gives me the following error, I don't know how to solve it. What does the error mean and how do I go about solving it if anything? I'm stuck.

```
<br />
<b>Recoverable fatal error</b>:  Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\getComments.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
```

After minotaurs suggestion and the removal of ->con from $querylines, it now says

```
    <br />
 <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\Apache24\htdocs\getComments.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\getComments.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />
```

Comment: You probably don't need the $ in `->$queryReplies`

Comment: @Nigel Ren, if I remove the $ it wont even load the script.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$resultReplies = $con->$queryReplies->execute();`

Because you included a `$` in your `$con->$queryReplies` part, PHP thinks you want to access a property of the `$con` object, while in reality you want to just use `$queryReplies`. Drop the `$con->` part.

Usually you look at the line where PHP says an error is occurring and you look at if something is wrong with that line. In this case you could know that `$queryReplies` contains a `mysql_stmt` object. At least that is what points me to the source of the error :).

Comment: Furthermore, at the start of your script you do `$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.id = 22 ";` and then go about executing that query to see if you should execute more code. Do you really want to execute the rest of your code only if a comment with ID 22 exists?

Comment: That solved the problem, however I now have another error of                         
 <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\Apache24\htdocs\getComments.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\getComments.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />                             The ID part is just for the specific page that I'm on, so comments related to that page only will come up.

Comment: To find the source of this problem, you can almost always do the following (taking your reported error as an example): Go to C:\Apache24\htdocs\getComments.php line 47. PHP says _Call to a member function fetch\_array() on boolean_. Where in that line is `fetch_array()` called, and on which variable is it called? Dump that variable using `var_dump($variable)` and you will see that `$variable` is an integer. Now you have to find out why it is an integer and not something that you can call `fetch_array()` on. That's up to you!

Comment: I managed to solve it. I needed to get the result by using get_result() from the executed statement. Thanks for helping.